# Deno cannot log info level

Tags: typescript, deno

I am working with Deno for the first time and I need to make a logger.
I get this weird error message:

> TS1205 [ERROR]: Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided requires using 'export type'.
> export { LogLevels, LevelName } from "./levels.ts";

I just want to log the INFO level, i tried doing this with this code:

```
await log.setup({
    handlers: {
        console: new log.handlers.ConsoleHandler("INFO")
    }, 
    loggers: {
        default: {
            level: "INFO",
            handlers: ["console"],
        }
    }
})
```

EDIT: Found out i used an outdated version of the log library.
changed my import from:

```
import * from "https://deno.land/std@0.63.0/log/mod.ts"
```

to:

```
import * from "https://deno.land/std/log/mod.ts"
```

Comment: Will you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The code snippet you provided doesn't show what library you're using, how you're importing it, etc.

Comment: Be sure to exercise caution when using [unversioned imports](https://deno.land/manual@v1.13.2/linking_to_external_code#how-do-i-import-a-specific-version-of-a-module), especially without a [lock file](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/integrity_checking).

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig.json:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "isolatedModules": false
      }
    }
```

After that you can execute code with:

```sh
    deno run -c tsconfig.json --allow-net --allow-read --unstable {your_entrypoint}.ts
```